# Problem with migrations in column unique and auto-increment using MySQL

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have a problem when I use the MySQL database in my project. In general, some project tables need to have an auto-incrementing field as data is entered. However, in MySQL a column except Id can only be auto-incrementing if it is unique key. For example:

```
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Code { get; set; }

    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

However, in MySQL a column except `Id` can only be auto-incrementing if it is unique key. For example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
    .HasIndex(c => c.Code)
    .IsUnique();
```

So far so good. The `Code` is correct and compiling. However, when generating migrations, the result is:

**Part 1:**

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Client",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
        Code = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
        Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 200, nullable: false),
        BirthDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Client", x => x.Id);
    }
);
```

**Part 2:**

```
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_Client_Code",
    table: "Client",
    column: "Code",
    unique: true);
```

Ao executar a atualização do banco de dados (`database update`) a seguinte mensagem é exibida: `Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`.

This error is caused by the way migrations is created. In part one of the code above it is already explicit that "Code" is `MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn` and so the error happens. To solve this problem, I had to create two migrations: the first adds only the `Code` field to single and the second inserts the auto increment. However, I would not want to use it this way, because every time I would have to create at least two migrations.

NOTE: I could give up the `GUID` `` and only use `Code` (`int`) for tables with this scenario, but this is not possible because I would have to modify the structure of all tables. Also, another possible solution I found was to make ID and Code the primary key, but I'm not yet likely to use it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to resolve this.

If you just want to **manually** fix the migration code, then do not use `CreateIndex`, but just add the alternate key to the constraints of the create table operation:

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Client",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
            Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 200, nullable: true),
            Code = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
                .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy",
                            MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
            BirthDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Client", x => x.Id);
            table.UniqueConstraint("AK_Client", x => x.Code); // <-- Add unique constraint
        });
}
```

There is not data annotation to define an alternate key, but you can use the **fluent API**:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Client>(entity => entity.HasAlternateKey(e => e.Code));
}
```

This will create the same working migration code as above and would result in the following `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Client` (
    `Id` char(36) NOT NULL,
    `Name` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
    `Code` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `BirthDate` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_Client` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    CONSTRAINT `AK_Client` UNIQUE (`Code`)
);
```

Using `HasIndex().IsUnique()` will not work, as this will generate a `CreateIndex()` call with the same problem you described in your question.